# Can I use the VSS ASR writer to create a bootable virtual disk image?

Tags: vhd, volume-shadow-service

I'm researching the way to create a .VHD file that would be bootable in Hyper-V.

Can I use the VSS ASR writer that's included in Windows 7 and Win 2k8 to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After additional research, it seems it is not as simple as this.  To achieve the type of functionality present in Disk-2-VHD requires consideration of block size, location of MBR in volume snapshots, and differences in the VSS systems across the various VSS implementations (i.e. xp vs vista vs 2k3 vs 2k8).  My original question is rather large in scope, and so this answer should only serve as a pointer to significant research required on this topic.